# Classification Model on Single Feature?

Tags: logistic, classification, cross-validation, random-forest, roc

this is my first time using StackExchange so forgive me if I commit any faux paus with this question, and it has only been a few months since I first started learning machine learning.

In my research, I'm developing a binary classification algorithm for cancer screening. I have two continuous numerical features. The AUC of Feature 1 is **0.7343**, and the AUC of Feature 2 is **0.5874**. All good, right? Both features have some predictive ability, and Feature 1 is stronger than Feature 2.

However, when I build an algorithm using only one feature at a time and cross-validate, the results are weird. When I do 10-fold stratified CV (averaged over 100 runs) with logistic regression using Feature 1 as the only input, I get an AUC of **0.7325** (reasonable enough). Using only Feature 2 as the only input gives me an AUC of **0.5087**; in other words, useless. My question is, why aren't the Feature 2 AUC's more similar (0.5874 vs. 0.5087)? A logistic model is monotonically increasing, so shouldn't the cross-validated AUC be essentially the same as the AUC without any model?

Even weirder: if I use a Random Forest classifier instead of logistic regression (Matlab's fitensemble function, 100 trees, using % of trees in each category for probability, average of 10 separate CV runs), I get a wonderful AUC of **0.8729** for Feature 1 but an abysmal AUC of **0.2504** for Feature 2.

What gives? Why are these results so weird? Is the heavenly AUC of 0.8729 real? I have a hard time believing that. The practical implication of this is that I'm trying to develop a classification model that utilizes both features (and possibly another) as inputs and am trying to show that it's better than each feature on its own. I don't have a large data set so I'm reporting the performance of the model that includes both features based on cross-validation rather than a fully independent test set. Am I "allowed" to compare the raw AUC's of the features by themselves sans model (0.7343 and 0.5874) with the cross-validation based AUC from my two-feature model? That's what I was doing but I'm confused with the results I'm getting when I build a single-feature model.

Any assistance is appreciated!

Comment: I avoid AUC.  The question with the random forest is whether you are over-fitting.  Try making a hold-out set first, then making the cv-based fit.  Test against the hold-out and look at the disparity between CV-based error on the training set and error in the hold-out set.  You are feeding it less information and that is going to move values around, but if your CV is doing its job, and you have enough information in your samples then gross incompatibilities wont be found - otherwise they will.  Look at a metric like AIC - it has a decent foundation in information theory and is harder to abuse.

Comment: (1) auc is okay (2) you don't mention sample size -so hard to tell if you're overfitting. The drop in AUC is c/w overfitting. (3) with only two predictors hard to believe RF model superior over simpler models  (4) sounds like you're not using appropriate metrics for RF model (oob estimates for model performance  (5) using auc for RF models can be an issue (6) auc of 0.25 is a bug/coding error

Comment: Thanks for the replies! This particular analysis is being run on 50 observations, 11 of which are positive.

Comment: Also, my understanding was that OOB estimates are unbiased and similar to LOOCV, so the reason I was using CV on the RF was to get the most equivalent comparisons with my other models, for which I am using 10-fold stratified CV. Is this reasoning not sound? Using OOB would certainly save computation time.

Comment: I plotted the decision boundary and found that five of the positive observations in Feature 1 have a very similar value, and the RF is learning this little horizontal strip. However, there is no reason that this value has any meaning (from a biological / image analysis perspective) so I think it's just a coincidence, making RF overfit.

Comment: Why not write a clean answer for posterity?